# Code digger in Visual studio 2013

Tags: c#

I am using vs 2013 and new to code digger. For the following code i had generated test data.

Code:

```
 public static int Test(int value)
    {
        if (value == 0)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (value <= 10)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (value <= 100)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }
```

Test data generated by code digger:

```
value result
  0     -1
  1     0
 11     1
 111    2
```

My actual doubt is, on what basis test data(value) has been generated by code digger to cover all paths. For an instance value 10 can also been used to get the result 0 but code digger generated 11.

Comment: Code digger is not part of VS. Please make sure to add link to what you mean - possibly https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nikolait/2013/04/23/introducing-code-digger-an-extension-for-vs2012/.

Comment: As specified in the website, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nikolait/2013/04/23/introducing-code-digger-an-extension-for-vs2012/..       Code digger generated the data as i specified. My doubt is on what calculation or on what logic these input values has been chosen.